# Is below code correct to call the Oracle procedure using unix shell script?

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, stored-procedures

```
                 #!/bin/ksh
                 sqlplus -s ip2339/***@dv42<<END
                 execute proc1;
                 commit;
                 exit;
                 END
```

I have created the procedure in database. While Executing am not getting the output.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your 'output' is coming from `dbms_output` statements in the procedure, and you aren't getting an exception you haven't mentioned, you need to turn on the display of those with `set serveroutput on`:

```sh
 #!/bin/ksh
 sqlplus -s ip2339/***@dv42<<END
 set serveroutput on
 execute proc1;
 commit;
 exit;
 END
```

Of course those are fairly significant assumptions...